# How to fix repast simphony error : saf.v3d.scene.VComposite.addChild(VComposite.java:46)

Tags: java, repast-simphony

I have a new error in my repast simphony model. When my agent give birth and I contextualize its childs in the context, the next step gives me an error like java.lang.NullPointerException (See source code).
Can you help me to fix it?

**`java.lang.NullPointerException`**

```
at saf.v3d.scene.VComposite.addChild(VComposite.java:46)
    at repast.simphony.visualizationOGL2D.SpatialWrapper.setChild(SpatialWrapper.java:80)
    at repast.simphony.visualizationOGL2D.SpatialWrapper.<init>(SpatialWrapper.java:34)
    at repast.simphony.visualizationOGL2D.StyledDisplayLayerOGL2D.createSpatial(StyledDisplayLayerOGL2D.java:146)
    at repast.simphony.visualizationOGL2D.StyledDisplayLayerOGL2D.processAdded(StyledDisplayLayerOGL2D.java:228)
    at repast.simphony.visualizationOGL2D.StyledDisplayLayerOGL2D.update(StyledDisplayLayerOGL2D.java:250)
    at repast.simphony.visualizationOGL2D.DisplayOGL2D.update(DisplayOGL2D.java:404)
    at repast.simphony.visualization.engine.DisplayComponentControllerAction$DisplayUpdater.execute(DisplayComponentControllerAction.java:44)
    at repast.simphony.engine.schedule.DefaultAction.execute(DefaultAction.java:38)
    at repast.simphony.engine.schedule.ScheduleGroup.executeList(ScheduleGroup.java:205)
    at repast.simphony.engine.schedule.ScheduleGroup.execute(ScheduleGroup.java:238)
    at repast.simphony.engine.schedule.Schedule.execute(Schedule.java:352)
    at repast.simphony.ui.GUIScheduleRunner$ScheduleLoopRunnable.run(GUIScheduleRunner.java:52)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2):

This error can occur if the `getVSpatial` method in the style for child agent returns null.

[JavaDoc for getVSpatial](https://repast.github.io/docs/api/repast_simphony/repast/simphony/visualizationOGL2D/StyleOGL2D.html#getVSpatial(T,saf.v3d.scene.VSpatial))

When the child is created the second argument to getVSpatial is null, so you need to be sure to return a VSpatial implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. The problem was my getVSpatial method who returned null.